# AS3: Timeline navigation with gotoAndStop(); throws unexpected null object error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Here's my code. It seems I can't address the stage. I get a null object reference error at gotoAndStop(3);

```js
  private function  exitInvitation(e: MouseEvent): void {
   simpleBack.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exitInvitation);
   removeChild(simpleBack);
   
   gotoAndPlay(3);
  }
```

I'm moving from frame 10 to frame 3. This is clearly a bug. Not even code written on the timeline  works. What do I have to listen for to know that my stage object is available?

I've tried adding:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

private function init(e:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    gotoAndPlay(3);
}
```

Sadly, it doesn't work.

Comment: You're not addressing the stage anywhere in provided code snippets. Why do you think you do?

Comment: Again one point to @Organis :)
The Class should extends a DisplayObject, Sprite or MovieClip to gain acces to stage.
But You don't provide the entire code or, You have no access to the stage property because there's no reference possible trough Your custom Class.
A bug? Nope, let us know if You find a bug :)

Comment: @tatactic The provided snippets are probably timeline scripts, not classes, they have all the **MovieClip** properties  available without explicitly subclassing **MovieClip**. My point was that there's no **stage** references in the code.

Comment: Sorry, @Organis  I have misunderstand this.
I'm not native English speaking, so I just try to learn English, and do my best to answer in the best way I can. :(
Sometimes I'm totally wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. Somehow my object was getting deleted from the stage.